# play framework + powermock => classNotFoundException

Tags: java, playframework, mockito, powermock

- powermock-mockito: 1.4.11
- mockito: 1.9.0
- play: 1.2.3

I am trying to mock a final class using powermock-mockito. For this you have to annotate the tested class with the @RunWith(PowerMockRunner) - annotation. However - I suppose - this seems to confuse play causing a ClassNotFoundException for my own tested class DropboxCrawlerTests:

```
A java.lang.ClassNotFoundException has been caught, mashpan.crawl.dropbox.DropboxCrawlerTests
```

DropboxCrawlerTests.java:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) 
@PrepareForTest(XContentBuilder.class)
public class DropboxCrawlerTests extends UnitTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Fixtures.deleteDatabase();
        Fixtures.loadModels("testusers.yaml");
        Cache.clear();
    }
..
}
```

EDIT:

Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mashpan.crawl.dropbox.DropboxCrawlerMultipleFilesTests
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.MockClassLoader.loadModifiedClass(MockClassLoader.java:143)
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.loadClass(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:65)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:133)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:39)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:217)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.(PowerMockRunner.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:31)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:24)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:29)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getRunner(Computer.java:38)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer$1.runnerForClass(Computer.java:29)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:93)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.runners(RunnerBuilder.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.(Suite.java:79)
    at org.junit.runner.Computer.getSuite(Computer.java:26)
    at org.junit.runner.Request.classes(Request.java:69)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:117)
    at play.test.TestEngine.run(TestEngine.java:101)
    at controllers.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:546)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:500)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:476)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:471)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:159)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.execute(PlayHandler.java:220)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:265)
    at play.server.PlayHandler$NettyInvocation.run(PlayHandler.java:200)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$101(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:165)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

EDIT2: that's the class I want to mock: http://semicomplete.com/doc/org/elasticsearch/common/xcontent/XContentBuilder.html

EDIT3:

the base class for testing DropboxCrawlerTests.java

```
package mashpan.crawl.dropbox;


import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import mashpan.index.ElasticSearch;
import mashpan.index.ServiceIndexes;
import mashpan.mailer.Mailer;
import mashpan.monitoring.ExceptionMonitor;
import mashpan.security.PBE;
import mashpan.utilities.UserUtility;
import models.DropboxAuthentication;
import models.DropboxFolder;
import models.User;

import org.elasticsearch.action.ListenableActionFuture;
import org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.action.bulk.BulkRequestBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.action.index.IndexRequestBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Ignore;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.*;
import org.mockito.internal.verification.Times;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.*;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.*;

import play.Logger;
import play.cache.Cache;
import play.test.Fixtures;
import play.test.UnitTest;

import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.Entry;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxException;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.WebAuthSession;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(XContentBuilder.class)
public class DropboxCrawlerTests extends UnitTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        Fixtures.deleteDatabase();
        Fixtures.loadModels("testusers.yaml");
        Cache.clear();
    }







    /*************** HELPERS ***************************/

//  example how to construct a real dropboxauthentication object
protected DropboxAuthentication createDefaultDropboxAuthentication(User user) {
    PBE pbe = new PBE("deroom1234".toCharArray());
    String secret = UserUtility.DROPBOXSECRET;
    String token = UserUtility.DROPBOXTOKEN;
    HashMap<String, byte[]> encrypted = pbe.encrypt(secret.getBytes());
    return new DropboxAuthentication(
            "document"
            , encrypted.get("cypher")
            , encrypted.get("iv")
            , token
            , secret
            , user
            , new Date());
}

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private DropboxCrawler createDefaultDropboxCrawler() throws DropboxException, IOException {
    User user = User.find("byEmail", UserUtility.EMAIL).first();


    DropboxAuthentication dropboxAuthentication = mock(DropboxAuthentication.class);
    dropboxAuthentication.user = user;

    Mailer mailer = mock(Mailer.class);

    ServiceIndexes indexer = mock(ServiceIndexes.class);

    XContentBuilder jsonBuilder = createJsonBuilder();

    ElasticSearch elasticsearch = createElasticSearchMock(jsonBuilder); 

    DropboxConnector dropboxConnector = createDropboxConnector(dropboxAuthentication);

    Logger.debug("[DropboxCrawlerTests] dropboxAuthentication.user="+user);

    ExceptionMonitor exceptionMonitor = mock(ExceptionMonitor.class);

    return new DropboxCrawler(user.email
            , dropboxAuthentication
            , mailer
            , indexer
            , elasticsearch
            , dropboxConnector
            , exceptionMonitor
            , jsonBuilder);
}

protected DropboxConnector createDropboxConnector(DropboxAuthentication dropboxAuthentication) throws DropboxException {
    String hash = "hash";
    Entry entry = mock(Entry.class);
    entry.hash = hash;
    entry.contents = new ArrayList<DropboxAPI.Entry>();
    DropboxAPI<WebAuthSession> dropboxAPI = mock(DropboxAPI.class);
    when(dropboxAPI.metadata("/", 0, null, true, null)).thenReturn(entry);

    DropboxConnector dropboxConnector = mock(DropboxConnector.class);
    when(dropboxConnector.connect(dropboxAuthentication)).thenReturn(dropboxAPI);

    return dropboxConnector;
}



protected XContentBuilder createJsonBuilder() throws IOException {
        XContentBuilder jsonBuilder = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder();
//      Class<? extends XContentBuilder> class1 = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().getClass();
//      Logger.debug("[DropboxCrawlerTests] class="+class1);
//      XContentBuilder jsonBuilder = mock(class1);
//      when(jsonBuilder.startObject()).thenReturn(jsonBuilder);
//      when(jsonBuilder.field(any(String.class), any(String.class))).thenReturn(jsonBuilder);
//      when(jsonBuilder.endObject()).thenReturn(jsonBuilder);
//      return jsonBuilder;
        return jsonBuilder;
    }

protected ElasticSearch createElasticSearchMock(XContentBuilder jsonBuilder) {
    IndexRequestBuilder indexRequestBuilder = mock(IndexRequestBuilder.class);
    when(indexRequestBuilder.setSource(jsonBuilder)).thenReturn(indexRequestBuilder);
    Client client = mock(Client.class);
    when(client.prepareIndex("dropbox", "documents")).thenReturn(indexRequestBuilder);
    BulkResponse bulkResponse = mock(BulkResponse.class);
    when(bulkResponse.hasFailures()).thenReturn(false);
    ListenableActionFuture actionFuture = mock(ListenableActionFuture.class);
    when(actionFuture.actionGet()).thenReturn(bulkResponse);
    BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequestBuilder = mock(BulkRequestBuilder.class);
    when(bulkRequestBuilder.execute()).thenReturn(actionFuture);
    ElasticSearch elasticsearch = mock(ElasticSearch.class);
    when(elasticsearch.getClient()).thenReturn(client);
    when(elasticsearch.newBulkRequest()).thenReturn(bulkRequestBuilder);

    return elasticsearch;
}

}
```

the actual test class DropboxCrawlMultipleFilesTests.java

```
package mashpan.crawl.dropbox;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import mashpan.crawl.main.*;
import mashpan.document.*;
import mashpan.index.ElasticSearch;
import mashpan.index.ServiceIndexes;
import mashpan.mailer.Mailer;
import mashpan.monitoring.ExceptionMonitor;
import mashpan.utilities.UserUtility;
import models.DropboxAuthentication;
import models.User;

import org.elasticsearch.action.ListenableActionFuture;
import org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.BulkResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.Client;
import org.elasticsearch.client.action.bulk.BulkRequestBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.action.index.IndexRequestBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentBuilder;
import org.junit.*;
import org.junit.runner.*;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.*;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.*;

import play.Logger;

import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI;
import com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI.Entry;
import com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxException;
import com.dropbox.client2.session.WebAuthSession;

public class DropboxCrawlerCrawlMultipleFilesTests extends DropboxCrawlerTests {
    /*************** Multiple Files+Folders ***********************/

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Test
    @Ignore
    public void crawl_multipleFiles_shouldSetFieldsForJsonBuilder() throws DropboxException, IOException {
        Logger.debug("[DropboxCrawlerTests] crawl_singleFolder_shouldAddItemsToBulkRequest");
        User user = User.find("byEmail", UserUtility.EMAIL).first();

        DropboxAuthentication dropboxAuthentication = createDefaultDropboxAuthentication(user);

        Mailer mailer = mock(Mailer.class);

        ServiceIndexes indexer = mock(ServiceIndexes.class);

        XContentBuilder jsonBuilder = createJsonBuilder();

        IndexRequestBuilder indexRequestBuilder = mock(IndexRequestBuilder.class);
        when(indexRequestBuilder.setSource(jsonBuilder)).thenReturn(indexRequestBuilder);
        Client client = mock(Client.class);
        when(client.prepareIndex("dropbox", "documents")).thenReturn(indexRequestBuilder);
        BulkResponse bulkResponse = mock(BulkResponse.class);
        when(bulkResponse.hasFailures()).thenReturn(false);
        ListenableActionFuture actionFuture = mock(ListenableActionFuture.class);
        when(actionFuture.actionGet()).thenReturn(bulkResponse);
        BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequestBuilder = mock(BulkRequestBuilder.class);
        when(bulkRequestBuilder.execute()).thenReturn(actionFuture);
        ElasticSearch elasticsearch = mock(ElasticSearch.class);
        when(elasticsearch.getClient()).thenReturn(client); 
        when(elasticsearch.newBulkRequest()).thenReturn(bulkRequestBuilder);

        Entry rootDir = mock(Entry.class);
        String rootHash = "hash";
        rootDir.hash = rootHash;
        rootDir.isDir = true;
        rootDir.contents = new ArrayList<DropboxAPI.Entry>();

        Entry subDir1 = mock(Entry.class);
        String subDir1Hash = "subDirHash";
        subDir1.hash = subDir1Hash;
        subDir1.isDir = true;
        subDir1.path = "subDir1";
        subDir1.contents = new ArrayList<DropboxAPI.Entry>();
        rootDir.contents.add(subDir1);

        Entry file1 = mock(Entry.class);
        String file1Hash = "file1Hash";
        file1.hash = file1Hash;
        file1.isDir = false;
        file1.contents = new ArrayList<DropboxAPI.Entry>();
        file1.modified = "12/06/2012"; //EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss ZZZZZ https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-java-sdk-1.2.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.Entry.html#modified
        file1.mimeType = "text/html";
        file1.rev = "file1";
        file1.path = subDir1.path+"/"+file1.rev;
        subDir1.contents.add(file1);

        Entry file2 = mock(Entry.class);
        String file2Hash = "file2Hash";
        file2.hash = file2Hash;
        file2.isDir = false;
        file2.contents = new ArrayList<DropboxAPI.Entry>();
        file2.modified = "12/06/2012"; //EEE, dd MMM yyyy kk:mm:ss ZZZZZ https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-java-sdk-1.2.3-docs/com/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI.Entry.html#modified
        file2.mimeType = "text/html";
        file2.rev = "file2";
        file2.path = subDir1.path+"/"+file2.rev;
        subDir1.contents.add(file2);

        Entry subDir2 = mock(Entry.class);
        String subDirHash2 = "subDirHash2";
        subDir2.hash = subDirHash2;
        subDir2.isDir = true;
        subDir2.contents = new ArrayList<DropboxAPI.Entry>();
        rootDir.contents.add(subDir2);



        DropboxAPI<WebAuthSession> dropboxAPI = mock(DropboxAPI.class);
        when(dropboxAPI.metadata("/", 0, null, true, null)).thenReturn(rootDir);
        DropboxConnector dropboxConnector = mock(DropboxConnector.class);
        when(dropboxConnector.connect(dropboxAuthentication)).thenReturn(dropboxAPI);

        ExceptionMonitor exceptionMonitor = mock(ExceptionMonitor.class);

        new DropboxCrawler(user.email
                , dropboxAuthentication
                , mailer
                , indexer
                , elasticsearch
                , dropboxConnector
                , exceptionMonitor
                , jsonBuilder)
            .crawl();

        fail();
        //TODO comment in
//      verifyJsonBuilder(user, jsonBuilder, file1);
//      verifyJsonBuilder(user, jsonBuilder, file2);
    }

    @Test
    //  @Ignore
    public void crawl_multipleFiles_bulkRequestBuilder() throws DropboxException, IOException {
        Logger.debug("[DropboxCrawlerTests] crawl_singleFolder_shouldAddItemsToBulkRequest");
        User user = User.find("byEmail", UserUtility.EMAIL).first();

        DropboxAuthentication dropboxAuthentication = createDefaultDropboxAuthentication(user);

        Mailer mailer = mock(Mailer.class);

        ServiceIndexes indexer = mock(ServiceIndexes.class);

        XContentBuilder jsonBuilder = createJsonBuilder();

        IndexRequestBuilder indexRequestBuilder = mock(IndexRequestBuilder.class);
        when(indexRequestBuilder.setSource(jsonBuilder)).thenReturn(indexRequestBuilder);
        Client client = mock(Client.class);
        when(client.prepareIndex("dropbox", "documents")).thenReturn(indexRequestBuilder);
        BulkResponse bulkResponse = mock(BulkResponse.class);
        when(bulkResponse.hasFailures()).thenReturn(false);
        ListenableActionFuture actionFuture = mock(ListenableActionFuture.class);
        when(actionFuture.actionGet()).thenReturn(bulkResponse);
        BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequestBuilder = mock(BulkRequestBuilder.class);
        when(bulkRequestBuilder.execute()).thenReturn(actionFuture);
        ElasticSearch elasticsearch = mock(ElasticSearch.class);
        when(elasticsearch.getClient()).thenReturn(client); 
        when(elasticsearch.newBulkRequest()).thenReturn(bulkRequestBuilder);

        Entry rootDir = mock(Entry.class);
        String rootHash = "hash";
        rootDir.hash = rootHash;
        rootDir.isDir = true;
        rootDir.contents = new ArrayList<DropboxAPI.Entry>();

        Entry subDir1 = mock(Entry.class);
        String subDir1Hash = "subDirHash";
        subDir1.hash = subDir1Hash;
        subDir1.isDir = true;
        subDir1.path = "subDir1";
        subDir1.contents = new ArrayList<DropboxAPI.Entry>();
        rootDir.contents.add(subDir1);



        String file1Hash = "dFile1Hash";
        String file1Rev = "dFile1Rev";
        Entry file1 = new Entry(createEntryMap(
                file1Hash
                , false
                , 4392763
                , "12/06/2012"
                , subDir1.path+"/"+file1Rev
                , false
                , "4.2MB"
                , null
                , null
                , "page_white_compressed"
                ));
        subDir1.contents.add(file1);

        String file2Hash = "dFile2Hash";
        String file2Rev = "dFile2Rev";
        Entry file2 = new Entry(createEntryMap(
                file2Hash
                , false
                , 4392763
                , "12/06/2012"
                , subDir1.path+"/"+file2Rev
                , false
                , "4.2MB"
                , null
                , null
                , "page_white_compressed"
                ));
        subDir1.contents.add(file2);

        Entry subDir2 = mock(Entry.class);
        String subDirHash2 = "subDirHash2";
        subDir2.hash = subDirHash2;
        subDir2.isDir = true;
        subDir2.contents = new ArrayList<DropboxAPI.Entry>();
        rootDir.contents.add(subDir2);


        DropboxAPI<WebAuthSession> dropboxAPI = mock(DropboxAPI.class);
        when(dropboxAPI.metadata("/", 0, null, true, null)).thenReturn(rootDir);
        when(dropboxAPI.metadata(subDir1.path, 0, null, true, null)).thenReturn(subDir1);
        when(dropboxAPI.metadata(subDir2.path, 0, null, true, null)).thenReturn(subDir2);
        DropboxConnector dropboxConnector = mock(DropboxConnector.class);
        when(dropboxConnector.connect(dropboxAuthentication)).thenReturn(dropboxAPI);

        ExceptionMonitor exceptionMonitor = mock(ExceptionMonitor.class);

        new DropboxCrawler(user.email
                , dropboxAuthentication
                , mailer
                , indexer
                , elasticsearch
                , dropboxConnector
                , exceptionMonitor
                , jsonBuilder)
            .crawl();

        verify(bulkRequestBuilder, times(2)).add(indexRequestBuilder);
        //TODO comment in
//      verifyJsonBuilder(user, jsonBuilder, file1);
//      verifyJsonBuilder(user, jsonBuilder, file2);
    }

    private HashMap<String,Object> createEntryMap(
            Object hash
            , Object thumb_exists
            , Object bytes
            , Object modified
            , Object path
            , Object is_dir
            , Object size
            , Object root
            , Object contents
            , Object icon) {

        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        if(hash != null)
            map.put("hash", hash);
        map.put("thumb_exists", thumb_exists);
        map.put("bytes", bytes);
        map.put("modified", modified);
        map.put("path", path);
        map.put("is_dir", is_dir);
        map.put("size", size);
        if(root != null)
            map.put("root", root);
        if(contents != null)
            map.put("contents", contents);
        if(icon != null)
            map.put("icon", icon);

        return map;
    }



    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private void verifyJsonBuilder(User user, XContentBuilder jsonBuilder,
            Entry file) throws IOException {
        verify(jsonBuilder).field("user", user.email);
        verify(jsonBuilder).field("type", "document");
        verify(jsonBuilder).field("mimetype", file.mimeType);
        verify(jsonBuilder).field("filename", Utils.dropExtension(file.fileName()));
        verify(jsonBuilder).field("revision", file.rev);
        String path = file.path.replaceAll("/", "");
        path = Utils.dropExtension(path);
        verify(jsonBuilder).field("path", path);
        verify(jsonBuilder).field("fullpath", file.path);
    }
}
```

Comment: A complete stacktrace would more useful. Anyway there is known issues between Mockito and Play Framework reloading. I suppose you are hitting the same with PowerMock. I strongly advise to drop a message on the PowerMock mailing list for advice.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem now. Have you found out, how to get this running?

Comment: sry no, switched to node..js ;-)